# Cocoapods sees a version thats not there

Tags: cocoapods

I have Cocoapods 1.12.1 installed on my machine and XCode 14.3, my coworker have the same setup and same Cocoapods version + XCode, he created Pod.lock, but why I pull his work and run

```
pod install
```

I get this error:

```
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.12.1) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.11.3). Incompatibility issues may arise.
```

And I see indeed that the pod.lock and pods got installed on my machine by 1.11.3! even tho I have 1.12.1

here is what I tried:

- tried installing pods again with homebrew and with sudo gem
- tried updating pods again with homebrew and with sudo gem
- tried listing all cocoapods version installed on my machine and I don't have 1.11.3 at all with
- tried cleaning pod cache with `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`
- tried linking Cocoapods again with `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`

and each of those actions responded back by either I already have 1.12.1 installed, I already have the latest version or that Cocoapods already linked `Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1`

Also worth mentioning Gem.lock also has 1.12.1.

What else can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Run `pod --version` and `which pod`, that will give you an insight where it's installed. If you have multiple Ruby versions, it's possible that each Ruby has its own CocoaPods version installed.

Comment: shows 1.12.1 as well @VadimBelyaev

Answer (score -1):

Your `Podfile.lock` was previously created by an earlier version of CocoaPods. The version of CocoaPods that was used to create the file is in the very end of `Podfile.lock`.

Once you run `pod install` with a newer version, `Podfile.lock` will show as modified.

All you need to do is commit the changes in `Podfile.lock` to Git. Subsequent runs of `pod install` will not issue this warning anymore.